# Java web application cannot connect to AWS RDS DB Instance

Tags: java, mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I created DB Instance (MySQL) with Publicly Accessible option. In DB Security group, I opened MySQL Port for EC2 instance security group(Web server). In EC2 security group it allows ssh, web server ports. I can able to connect DB Instance from EC2 instance. I deployed web app on web server and it can't able to connect with RDS Instance.

I am getting the exception in my local web server:

> org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not
>   get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Server
>   connection failure during transaction. Due to underlying exception:
>   'java.net.UnknownHostException:
>   "kbawstry2.cdhtaamn5ynq.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com"'.

**EC2 Security Group**
[image: EC2 Security Group]

**DBInstance Security Group**
[image: DBInstance Security Group]

Using MySQL WorkBench, I can connect to RDS DB Instance using TCP/IP SSH Tunnelling option. But in Java Programming How can I connect with database?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you also tell the outbound rule for your ec2 instance security group?

Comment: All traffic are opened in outbound both in EC2 Security group and DB Instance Security Group.

Comment: What DNS server is configured for the EC2 instance?

Comment: Really, I don't know. I installed and configure apache-tomcat 7 for deploying web apps.

Comment: @KumareshBabu Could you share the code, where DB connection code is written ?

Comment: dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://" + dbUrl + ":" + port + "/"
     + dbName + "?autoReconnect=true");
   dataSource.setUsername(username);
   dataSource.setPassword(password);

Comment: I used dbUrl as RDS DB Instance Endpoint.

Comment: It is necessary to attach an IAM role with RDS permission?

Comment: @KumareshBabu its not necessary as you are not directly accessing RDS , you are accessing it from EC2 , which in turn has access to RDS, mentioned in Inbound rule of RDS. Could you please share your code on github if its not private code , i'll try from my side.

Comment: @AmitK I got code from github. Link is https://github.com/shephertz/App42PaaS-Java-MySQL-Sample

Comment: @KumareshBabu Thanks , i'll look into this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132661/discussion-between-amitk-and-kumaresh-babu).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I solved the issue. The problem is in application the way I mentioned connection string. I rectified and tested application in localhost then updated to tomcat server in EC2 instance. Another change in DB Security Group. I replaced source ip as EC2 instance's private IP address as both RDS and EC2 Instance are in same VPC.

Now It is working fine.

Comment: it would be better if you mention what did you change in the connection string as well.

Comment: In code, I was mentioned double quotes for connection string so it was getting failed to connect with RDS database. Next I rectified the problem made it works.

Comment: I faced same error but in my case i haven't configured rule as well. I removed double quotes from property file, Its started working fine.